# "Пожилой" и "старик": со скольких лет?

Tags: значение-слов

"В местах заключения содержится 238 000 пожилых людей – мужчин и женщин старше 50 лет" - это из записки Берии от 26.3.1953. Получается, что пожилыми тогда считались с 50 лет. А как с этим сейчас, и как менялся пожилой и старый возраст со временем?

Answer (score 3):

При всём разнобразии словарных толкований (формальное количество лет, признаки старения, солидность, жизненный опыт) я бы выделил определяющими **внешние признаки старения** и отметил бы относительность оценки кого-то как пожилого человека. Нет юридического статуса "пожилого человека" и не все выглядят на свой возраст. Это прежде всего субъективная оценка со стороны, по внешности или каким-то знаниям о человеке. Относительность оценки проявляется в таких ситуациях, как напр. суждение о возрасте жениха ("пожилой" - заметно старше невесты). Помимо понятия "пожилой человек" (букв. человек, успевший пожить немало), в современном языке широко применяется вторичное "пожилой возраст" ("уступайте места людям пожилого возраста" - их предлагается определить по внешности). Я воспринимаю это как элемент сниженного стиля, почти канцеляризм, подобный "импортному производству". Стариком мы называем человека почти обязательно седого, морщинистого, с трудом передвигающегося, зачастую с потухшим взглядом - т.е. по внешности и манере держаться; я бы не назвал стариком напр. журналиста Познера, которому 80 лет. С недавних пор "старость" существует не только в оценочном смысле, но и в формальном толковании ("пенсия по старости", измеряемой количеством прожитых лет), наряду с такими терминами, как "время дожития". Без этого она оставалась бы субъективной, оценочной категорией (ему помирать пора, а не жениться), зависящей ещё и от продолжительности жизни в ту или иную эпоху. Что касается Берии, у него могли быть соображения чисто практические: для него это были прежде всего люди, от которых нужен был тяжёлый физический труд - его система была не последним элементом тогдашней экономики, и "пожилые" для него могло означать выработанный за десятилетия ресурс.

Comment: Что касается старухи-процентщицы, то  "Это была крошечная, сухая старушонка, лет шестидесяти, с вострыми и злыми глазками, с маленьким вострым носом и простоволосая."   Формулировка "пенсия по старости" встречается уже в законе от 14.7.1956 "О государственных пенсиях"  (http://russia.bestpravo.ru/ussr/data04/tex16184.htm).

Comment: Да, насчёт процентщицы не подтверждается: в сети поиском по тексту исследователи этого распространённого утверждения нашли только возраст её сестры (35 лет), матери Раскольникова (40 лет) и хозяйки жилья (43 года) - убираю. Я бы не стал этого упоминать, если бы не услышал от человека, внушающего доверие. Это сказал Виталий Третьяков в авторской передаче на канале Культура (никто из присутствовавших не возразил), а он как-никак в МГУ преподаёт.

Comment: Что касается пенсий, видимо, формулировка менялась. В последнем законе СССР (90 года - не удалось найти действовавший перед этим) этот вид пенсии в определении назван "по возрасту (по старости)" и сделана сноска, что в дальнейшем тексте закона именуется только "по возрасту".

Answer (score 2):

Представители Российской академии медицинских наук говорят о том, что в последнее время произошли заметные изменения в определении биологического возраста человека. Для изучения таких и многих других изменений, происходящих с человеком, существует Всемирная организация здравоохранения – ВОЗ. Так, классификация возраста человека по ВОЗ, говорит следующее: в диапазоне от 25 до 44 лет – человек молод; в диапазоне от 44 до 60 – имеет средний возраст; с 60 до 75 – люди считаются пожилыми людьми; с 75 до 90 – это уже представители старого возраста. Все, кому посчастливилось перешагнуть эту планку, считаются долгожителями.- Читайте подробнее на FB.ru: http://fb.ru/article/178846/pojiloy-vozrast-po-klassifikatsii-voz---eto-skolko-kakoy-vozrast-schitaetsya-pojilyim                                     Новые возрастные границы укладываются в мироощущение современного человека. Согласно проведённому в этом году социологическому исследованию, каждый четвёртый европеец уверен, что старость наступает в 64 года, почти каждый пятый – что в 74 года. Социологические опросы проводились в 31 стране, опрошено более 40 тысяч человек, результаты обобщил британский профессор Доминик Абрамс. Выяснилось, что на Западе 80-летние люди ощущают уход молодости в 52 года, а приход старости - в 69 лет. Женщины  отодвигают начало своего увядания ещё дальше. Поменял возрастные рамки и кризис среднего возраста. Полсотни лет назад он наступал в 36 лет, сегодня - в 55.